# I can't figure out what's going on. I add an object to the array, it is added, but the old data copies the values from the new object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't figure out what's going on. I add an object to the array, it is added, but the old data copies the values from the new object. This is the first time I've encountered this.

Here is the code

```
      var news = []
      var next
      if(cart === null){
        next = 0
      }else {
        next = cart.length
      }
      switch(type){
        case 'horizontal':
          config['0']['type'] = type
          config['0']['id'] = next
          config['0'].idImg = selectSvg
          if(cart === null || cart === undefined || cart.length < 1){
            news.push(config)
            setCountCart(news.length)
            localStorage.setItem('cart-tagstyle', JSON.stringify(news))
            setCart(news)
          }else {
            var news = cart.slice()
            console.log(news);
            news.push(config)
            console.log(news);
            setCountCart(news.length)
            localStorage.setItem('cart-tagstyle', JSON.stringify(news))
            setCart(news)
          }
          break;
```

I tried it without push, according to the following index, the same thing. I searched the Internet, it didn't help. I've been suffering for the second day

Comment: Assuming you're using React but haven't tagged the question with it: [here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Answer (score 1):

```
config['0']['type'] = type
config['0']['id'] = next
config['0'].idImg = selectSvg
```

Due to this old data copies value from new objects. Check the below code where the index is changed

```
config[next]['type'] = type
config[next]['id'] = next
config[next].idImg = selectSvg
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand the problem correctly,
the problem is that because arrays are reference types. Which means when you assign an array to a variable, you're assigning a memory address and not the actual array itself,
so you should use **deep clone** for solving that or use

```
const newArray = [...oldArray];
```

than changing `newArray` will not effects `oldArray`

checkout this link for more info
https://dev.to/samanthaming/how-to-deep-clone-an-array-in-javascript-3cig

Comment: Note: `[...oldArray]` is a _shallow copy_